# Unable to query with GQL an existing Model

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, gql

I have a file named DB.py with the following class:

```
class ChannelToUserTable(ndb.Model):
    user_id = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=UsersTable)
    channel = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=ChannelsTable)
```

and also at the same file I have the following class for gql queries:

```
class Query(object):
    def __init__(self, query_str):
        self.__query = ndb.gql(query_str)

    def results(self):
        return self.__query
```

When I try to execute the following query:

```
DB.Query('''SELECT * FROM ChannelToUserTable WHERE ChannelToUserTable.channel=''' + ch_id).results()
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Model ChannelToUserTable has no property named u'ChannelToUserTable'
```

but when trying to execute the same query without the WHERE condition - I get a  perfectly correct result.

Any ideas?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your query should contain

> ...WHERE channel=...

instead of

> ...WHERE ChannelToUserTable.channel=...